# 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Tags: python, string, date, datetime, strftime

I am getting this error in my script

> 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'

```
df.set_index('Profile_ID', inplace=True)
df['CohortGroup'] = df.groupby(level=0)['Date_of_Service_Requested'].min().apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m')) 
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.head()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strftime` is a `datetime` method, not a `str` method. You can create a `datetime` series using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date_column': ['2019-03-15', '2016-12-05'],
                   'other_column': [10, 4]})
df['date_column'] = pd.to_datetime(arg=df['date_column'], 
                                   format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['date_column'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m'))
```